# Why normalising by dividing with 255 is required and other doubts related to log transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing

The following is my code for log transform in MATLAB:

```
clc
clear all
image = imread('image.jpg')
imaged = double(image) / 255
new_image = log(1 + imaged)
subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(image)
title('Before log transformation');
subplot(1, 2, 2) 
%new_image = uint8(new_image)
imshow(new_image)
title('After log transformation');
```

- Why do we need to convert `uint8` to `double`? (Doesn't seem to work without doing this)
- Why is normalising by dividing with 255 required? (I had written a code previously without such normalising and it worked fine, but here it malfunctions)
- Why does it give awrong image if I convert the image back to `uint8`? (Same as above, it worked fine for a different operation. In fact,it used to malfunction if I didn't convert back to `uint8`)

Code of other operation :

```
clear all
close all
clc
image = imread('city.jpg');
imaged = double(image);
maxI = max(max(max(imaged)));
minI = min(min(min(imaged)));
new_image = ((imaged - minI) ./ max(imaged - minI)) * 255;
subplot(1, 2, 1)
imshow(image)
title('Before min-max transformation');
subplot(1, 2, 2) 
new_image = uint8(new_image);
imshow(new_image)
title('After min-max transformation');
```

Comment: uint8 images have a range of 0..255. double images have a range of 0.0..1.0. If your images are not in those ranges, they will not display properly. I can't tell you why it worked differently in another script because we don't have the code.

Comment: @beaker I've added the code. _'If your images are not in those ranges, they will not display properly.'_ Which ranges exactly? uint8 or double?

Comment: What exactly does "Doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: Also, `min(imaged(:))`, same for `max`. Matlab is great at lazy copying, so this won't copy the data.

Comment: @MadPhysicist It used to return a completely white/black window instead of the colored image.

Comment: There's a problem in your transform. I've addressed it in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [@anonymous's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132106/2988730) is excellent and should at the very least be upvoted, I want to take a closer look at some specific things you do, so you know where to look next time.

Starting with your first concern about the conversion to `double` in `imaged = double(image)/255`. What happens when you divide a `uint8` value, which is between 0 and 255 by 255? You get a value between 0 and 1 of course. But what if the output is still a `uint8`, e.g., because the input array is `uint8`? Well, then the value wouldn't be *between* zero or one. It would be *either* zero *or* one (also of course), and with the proper dynamic range adjustment, you'd see a purely black and white image. The conversion to `double` makes it possible to get values between zero and one.

Pretty much all the other questions you have revolve around the fact that MATLAB understands two displayable image formats: `double`s in the range [0, 1], and `uint8` in the range [0, 255].

Your transform is expecting a number in the range [0, e-1] in order to produce an output in the range [0, 1]. The actual logarithm ends up being over numbers in the range [1, 2]. This is a potential bug in your code. You should either do

```
imaged = (e-1) * double(image)/255
```

or equivalently

```
new_image = log(1 + (e-1) * imaged)
```

or better yet

```
new_image = log2(1 + imaged)
```

Either of these options will prevent you from truncating your input's dynamic range unnecessarily.

If you're still wondering why you need to normalize by 255, see what happens to 255 when you pass is it unnormalized through the transform.

Your conversion back to `uint8` fails because you aren't doing it the same way as you did in the "other" code. The other code correctly maps the range [0, 1] to [0, 255]. Your current code just converts the values. As discussed before, a `uint8` can only be zero *or* one, not something in between.

In the "other" code, you first expanded your dynamic range to 255 with the statement `new_image = ((imaged-minI)./max(imaged-minI))*255;`. Remember that since `imaged` is a `double` in this case, so is `new_image`. However, doubles only display correctly in the range [0, 1]. Once you convert to `uint8`, the range [0, 255] becomes suitable for display.

Answer (score 4):

> -Why do we need to convert uint8 to double?(Doesn't seem to work without doing this)

To achieve more precision in calculation. Integer values have problems with division and rounding off real values. For instance, 5/2 is 2. But, 5.0/2.0 is 2.5.

> -Why is normalising by dividing with 255 required? (I had written a code previously without such normalising and it worked fine, but here it malfunctions)

To put them in 0-255 range which is a valid range for RGB values.

> -Why does it give wrong image if I convert the image back to uint8?(same as above, it worked fine for a different operation. in fact,it used to malfunction if I didn't convert back to uint8)

It losses it precision. For instance, 7/8 is 0. But, 7.0/8.0 is 0.875.